# ordering nvarchar values with number

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have The query below which returns all the questions and orders them by book reference which is working fine but the issue i am having is that book reference is a NvarChar filed type, example values 'Chapter 1 section 1' , 'Chapter 10 section 1','Chapter 3' 'Chapter 2 section 1'.

I would like to the problem that is coming up is the the data is being returned in that orrder

```
Select * from quest order by bookReferance asc
```

Comment: You should refactor your database and add a table `BookReferance` which contains `Chapter` and `Section` as `int`. Then you could link to it via foreign-key and `Order By bookRef.Chapter ASC, bookRef.Section ASC`.

Comment: You might want to consider switching to using the `hierarchyid` data type as the actual storage type and just re-interpreting that into Chapter, Section, etc elements when presenting these values to the user.

Comment: Add a sortOrder column to quest and use that for sorting.

Comment: the people that i want am making the system for are adament that they want to keep as it is. any ideas how i can chnage it si that it orders it and keeps the number

Comment: People who are qualified to make business decisions about how things **appear** are rarely qualified to come up with good database designs. The way that data is *formatted* for presentation should **not** dictate how that data is stored.